# BlockingCollection with ConcurrentQueue still remain object after GetConsumingEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, concurrency, queue

I have 2 threads, one is put data to IBlockingColection, and the second read it then send to kafka.
My application is asp.net core api.

```cs
public class ConcurrentQueueForEvents
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<IDomainEvent>  _queue;
    public ConcurrentQueueForEvents()
    {
        _queue = new BlockingCollection<IDomainEvent>(new ConcurrentQueue<IDomainEvent>());
    }
    public void Enqueue(IDomainEvent item)
    {
        _queue.Add(item);
        OnItemEnqueued();
    }

    public bool TryDequeue(out IDomainEvent result)
    {
        result = _queue.Take();
        return true;
    }
   public IEnumerable<IDomainEvent> GetConsumingEnumerable()
    {
        return _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable();
    }
public event EventHandler? ItemEnqueued;

    void OnItemEnqueued()
    {
        ItemEnqueued?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

at the controller, when user act an api, i send event to it, it was register as singleton on `StartUp` class

```cs
    public class PushEventToKafkaHandler 
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueueForEvents _queue;
    private readonly MessageBrokerFactory _messageBrokerFactory;
    private readonly IIntegrateEventMapper _mapper;
    private readonly AsyncDuplicateLock _locker = new ();

    
    public PushEventToKafkaHandler(ConcurrentQueueForEvents queue, 
        MessageBrokerFactory messageBrokerFactory, IIntegrateEventMapper mapper)
    {
        _queue = queue;
        _messageBrokerFactory = messageBrokerFactory;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
    
    public async Task Delivery()
    {
        foreach (var value in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            var targetMessage = _mapper.GetIntegrateEventFromEvent(value);
            var s = _messageBrokerFactory.GetSender(targetMessage.MessageType.Name);
            //await Task.Run(() =>
            //{
             //   s.SendAsync(targetMessage);
            //});
            Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} ---- {_queue.GetHashCode()}");
        }
    }

    public void DeliveryByHook()
    {
        _queue.ItemEnqueued += async (sender, args) =>
        {
            try
            {
                _queue.TryDequeue(out var message);
                if (message is IIntegrateEvent @event)
                {
                    var targetMessage = _mapper.GetIntegrateEventFromEvent(message);
                    var s = _messageBrokerFactory.GetSender(targetMessage.MessageType.Name);
                    await s.SendAsync(targetMessage);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            
        };
    }
}
```

this is the pusher that push event to kafka.

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env){
       var transporter = serviceProvider.GetService<PushEventToKafkaHandler>()!;
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            transporter.Delivery();
        });
}
```

at `StartUp` I run it on other thread by `Task.Run` but, when i call api to send event, the `transporter` keep remain item on `IBlockingCollection`.

So when i send 5 times event, instead of sending 5 message, he send total 15 (1+2+3+4+5) messages.

What i wrong here?

update:

after adding log the result is:

```
] [User.Api] [::1] [1f4f4db8-b260-4cc6-bf87-5ab8d68ecc0a] Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST https://localhost:7162/bet application/json 248 - 200 - application/json;+charset=utf-8 89.7223ms
14 ---- 6555496
14 ---- 6555496
14 ---- 6555496
14 ---- 6555496
14 ---- 6555496
```

at the 5th of api hitting

Comment: Note that you never await the `s.SendAsync` (and I'm not sure what the purpose of the `Task.Run` wrapping it is), but I doubt that's the cause of your problem

Comment: I suspect the problem is in `s.SendAsync` -- I can't see any way that the blocking collection would behave in the way you describe

Comment: No that is not the problem, i tried comment it and replaced by console.write, but it print 3 -4-5 times

Comment: You may have multiple queues, then, or perhaps you're adding the items multiple times somehow. Try logging `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` and `_queue.GethashCode()` inside the `Console.WriteLine`

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes, it is my prototype to try some approach, before trying with BlockingCollection<T>, i use ConcurrentQueue, and the event `ItemEnqueued ` i use to notify to `PushEventToKafkaHandler ` thread. and yes, i will update on my code

Comment: @canton7, after adding `Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} ---- {_queue.GetHashCode()}");` on the code, the same result each hit api time:14 ---- 655549, in the next, and next hit, the result is same, but be x2,x3 and x5 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after try with sample code, it is my mistake on code.
the caller of `Enqueue` method is register as singleton, and not flush event after enqueue.
so it keep message, then increase it each api hitting